# Selecting multiple values within a timestamp interval

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a (MySQL) table that looks like this:

```
`radiostation_id` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
`song_id` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
`date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
`length` int(4) NOT NULL
```

What I want to do is to find every same `song_id` that has been played within an interval of 15 minutes. It could be that the song was played for example today 15:10 and then again 15:20. So it shouldnt be that i need to set the interval myself, it should check for any interval through the table and list all the songs and timestamps it happened.

Comment: not sure what you mean, but song_id is in a relation with another table, public_songs, i always use UUID() instead of ai inc id in tables. Doesnt really matter because that table wont be used, it just contains the sond title and so on.

Comment: Last 15 minutes or any 15 minutes interval of your choice?

Comment: Any 15 minute interval, could be that the sound was played 3 days ago witha an interval within 15 minutes, then i want to get that result from a SQL-query

Comment: @JonasRogander so do you mean, for example, any song played between 12:00 and 12:15 on any given day?

Comment: @McAdam331, Yes, but i dont want to set a specific time, it should check any time and any date by itself, and list the songs that have been played within a 15 minute interval

Comment: @JonasRogander this can't be done arbitrarily. You'll need to specify at the *very* least a start or end time. Do you know how many combinations of 15 minutes there are in a 24 hour period? What exactly are your requirements here?

Comment: @McAdam331 I know, but its just a one time run so its not something im gonna use often. Im just trying to clean a table thats why i need the query. I updated the question btw.

Comment: @JonasRogander so you don't want all songs played in a 15 minute interval, but any song played twice in 15 minutes. the two are very different.

Comment: @McAdam331 Excactly! :)

Comment: @JonasRogander well then I've edited my answer, hopefully it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you want a song that is played within a certain 15 minutes regardless of the day. There are [date and time functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html) you can use to parse the information you want. For example, you can use `TIME()` to extract the time portion of your column. For example, you can search for any song played between 12:00 and 12:15 like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id
FROM myTable
WHERE TIME(timeColumn) BETWEEN '12:00:00' AND '12:15:00';
```

Here is a little [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/103ead/1) I used to try it.

**EDIT**

Based on our discussions in the comments, you can use the following query. It will self join the table on the condition that the song_id matches (so you can compare individual songs), the condition that the time is not exactly the same (so no occurrence is counted twice) and on the condition that the interval in the second table is within +/- 15 minutes of the first like this:

```
SELECT m.song_id, m.timecolumn
FROM myTable m
JOIN myTable mt 
  ON m.song_id = mt.song_id
  AND m.timeColumn != mt.timeColumn
  AND mt.timeColumn BETWEEN DATE_SUB(m.timeColumn, INTERVAL 15 MINUTE) AND DATE_ADD(m.timeColumn, INTERVAL 15 MINUTE);
```

Here is an updated [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/000975/5).

Comment: Hi and thanks for the reply. Thats excactly what im looking for, but i want it to search for ANY time, not just between 12:00 -> 12:15.

Comment: You can always change your bounds to query for a different time frame.

Comment: @JonasRogander if this doesn't do what you want, please edit your question with some sample data and expected results and I will try to help some more.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you are asking.

If you want to find occurrences of the *same* `song_id`, where a second row with the same `song_id` has a date value within 15 minutes of the first row, one way to get that would be a query like this:

```
SELECT t.song_id
  FROM looks_like_this t
 WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                  FROM looks_like_this s 
                 WHERE s.song_id = t.song_id
                   AND s.date >= t.date 
                   AND s.date <= t.date + INTERVAL 15 MINUTE
                   AND NOT (s.radiostation_id = t.radiostation_id AND s.date = t.date)
```

If you want to return a unique list of `song_id`, then add either `DISTINCT` keyword or a `GROUP BY t.song_id` clause.

Another way to get the result would be use a JOIN operation:

```
SELECT t.song_id
  FROM looks_like_this t
  JOIN looks_like_this s
    ON s.song_id = t.song_id
   AND s.date >= t.date
   AND s.date <= t.date + INTERVAL 15 MINUTE
   AND NOT (s.radiostation_id = t.radiostation_id AND s.date = t.date)
 GROUP BY t.song_id
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will show you all the rows where the last played is in the last 15 minutes.

```
SELECT * FROM myTable
WHERE date>= NOW() - INTERVAL 15 MINUTE
```

Note that using date in a table column is bad practice as it is a reserved mysql word.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to list out all the songs, when they were played and connect to the same song if it was played again within 15 minutes later.

```
select  pt1.ID, pt1.StartDate, pt2.StartDate StartDate2
from    PlayTimes  pt1
join    PlayTimes  pt2
    on  pt2.ID = pt1.ID
    and pt2.StartDate > pt1.StartDate
    and pt2.StartDate <= Date_Add( pt1.StartDate, interval 15 minute );
```

You didn't mention if the radio station played any role. The query above will return a song if it was play again within 15 minutes even on a different station. This makes sense. If you need only those songs played again within 15 minutes on the same station, then add the station id to the join criteria. Would a station ever do that (play the same song twice within 15 minutes)? Or are you checking to make sure a station never does that?